# AKS timeout container kubectl Rollout status check failed

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, kubectl

I have a sporadic issue that I am struggling to understand - azure pipeline on promote fails due to kubectl rollout status Deployment/name --timeout 120s --namespace xyz

I have tried to increase the progressDeadlineSeconds, but I know it may not take, I have tried to update the replicaSets to 2 so it can take but it still does not apply.  I am not fully understanding this error and there is a roll out issue.

Yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: #{KubeComponentName}#
  namespace: #{Namespace}#
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: #{KubeComponentName}#
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: #{ReplicaCount}#
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: #{KubeComponentName}#
      annotations:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
      serviceAccountName: #{KubeComponentName}#
      containers:
      - name: #{KubeComponentName}#
        image: #{ImageRegistry}#/datahub/#{KubeComponentName}#:latest
        #command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--"]
        #args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
        volumeMounts:
        ports:
        env:
        - name: NodeName
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: PodName
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name   
        - name: PodNamespace
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: PodIp
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: PodServiceAccount
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
        - name: ComponentInfo__ComponentName
          value: #{KubeComponentName}#
        - name: ComponentInfo__ComponentHost
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName              
        - name: ComponentInfo__ServiceUser
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName  
        - name: MongoDbUserName
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-xyz-username
              key: secret-value
        - name: MongoDbPassword
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-xyz-password
              key: secret-value
        - name: MongoDbKubernetesHosts
          value: #{MongoDbKubernetesHosts}#
        - name: MongoDbScriptBasePath
          value: #{MongoDbScriptBasePath}#
      volumes:
```

My errors keep happening such that I get a timeout error waiting for rollout or exceeded progress deadline

```
----

/opt/vsts-agent/_work/_tool/kubectl/1.18.6/x64/kubectl rollout status Deployment/datahub-recon --timeout 120s --namespace xyz
Waiting for deployment "datahub-recon" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
error: timed out waiting for the condition
##[error]Error: error: timed out waiting for the condition
/opt/vsts-agent/_work/_tool/kubectl/1.18.6/x64/kubectl describe Deployment datahub-recon --namespace xyz


Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    True    ReplicaSetUpdated
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   datahub-recon-567c7d6958 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  2m1s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set datahub-recon-567c7d6958 to 1
For more information, go to https://dev.azure.com/pbc/Premera/_environments/23
##[error]Rollout status check failed.


----
/opt/vsts-agent/_work/_tool/kubectl/1.18.6/x64/kubectl rollout status Deployment/datahub-recon --timeout 120s --namespace xyz
error: deployment "datahub-recon" exceeded its progress deadline
##[error]Error: error: deployment "datahub-recon" exceeded its progress deadline
/opt/vsts-agent/_work/_tool/kubectl/1.18.6/x64/kubectl describe Deployment datahub-recon --namespace xyz

Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:  datahub-recon-6bc6f85fc6 (2/2 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   datahub-recon-bd7d9754 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  13m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set datahub-recon-bd7d9754 to 1
For more information, go to https://dev.azure.com/pbc/Premera/_environments/23
##[error]Rollout status check failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue

check your

1-- Go to your release Pipeline --> click on edit and choose --> Deploy to AKS
2-- check the tasks  --> recheck all variables .

In my case I corrected the container name which was incorrect and it fixed the issue .

Check your code , see the yaml file and make sure the variables are same in the release pipeline.